# How to get a specific hex char from a uint256?

Tags: solidity, bit-manipulation

lets say I have the following uint256 value: `0x70997970c51812dc3a010c7d01b50e0d17dc79c8000403`

This uint256 is packed with various data that I would like to be able to parse.

How would I extract the value `4` (third number from the right) or the value `3` (last number)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use right shift >> in order to move to the rigth the item that you want

for example if you want the index 1 (from rigth to left) you need to move one times to the rigth

and because every hexadecimal value needs 4 bits to be represented you need to multiply by 4

```
uint move = index * 4;
```

and then you can use the and operator in order to clear the rest of the numbers

```
  function getParsed(uint256 value, uint index) external pure returns (uint cleared){
    uint move = index * 4;
    return (value >> move) & 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f ;        
}
```

so if you send the parameters:

0x00000000000000000070997970c51812dc3a010c7d01b50e0d17dc79c8000403 and 0 you will get the 3

0x00000000000000000070997970c51812dc3a010c7d01b50e0d17dc79c8000403 and 1 you will get the 0

0x00000000000000000070997970c51812dc3a010c7d01b50e0d17dc79c8000403 and 1 you will get the 4

---

if you want to use yul:

```
   function getParsed(bytes32 value, uint index) external pure returns (uint8 cleared){
     assembly {          
        let move := mul(index,4)
        let shifted := shr(move, value)    
        cleared := and(0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f,shifted)       
    }
}
```

this line here:

```
 let move := mul(index,4)
```

use [mul](https://www.evm.codes/#02?fork=arrowGlacier) in order to get the multiplication in the our example index = 1 so the result will be 4 (1*4)

and then you need to use [shr](https://www.evm.codes/?fork=arrowGlacier) in order to shift to the rigth

```
let shifted := shr(move, value)
```

and finally we use [and](https://www.evm.codes/#16?fork=arrowGlacier) in order to clear our value